Why does `dplyr::across()` substitute the symbol `.x` for the current column in a two-sided formula `.x ~ .x`, but not in a one-sided formula `~.x`?
I'm writing a function that takes a two sided formula with a purrr-style lambda expression on either side, e.g. f(.x) ~ g(.x) and converts those lambdas into two functions \(.x) f(.x) and \(.x) g(.x). This is a simplified version:
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

formula_to_function_pair <- function(f) {
  f_env <- f_env(f)
  list(
    lhs_fun = new_function(args = pairlist2(.x = ,), body = f_lhs(f)),
    rhs_fun = new_function(args = pairlist2(.x = ,), body = f_rhs(f))
  )
}

pair <- formula_to_function_pair(sum(.x) ~ mean(.x))
pair$lhs_fun(1:3) # Sum
#> [1] 6
pair$rhs_fun(1:3) # Mean
#> [1] 2

When I use this function within dplyr::across(), the placeholder symbol .x is replaced with the symbol for the current column, y in this case. This makes the pair of functions in terms of y, but I would like them to still be in terms of .x - i.e. function(.x) sum(.x) and function(.x) mean(.x).

# `.x ~ .x` is evaluated as `y ~ y`
tibble(y = 0L) %>%
  mutate(
    across(y, ~ list(formula_to_function_pair(sum(.x) ~ mean(.x))))
  ) %>%
  pull(y)
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]]$lhs_fun
#> function (.x) 
#> sum(y)
#> <environment: 0x10a6d24a8>
#> 
#> [[1]]$rhs_fun
#> function (.x) 
#> mean(y)
#> <environment: 0x10a6d24a8>

When I use a one-sided formula ~.x instead, I get the result that I want within dplyr::across() - the pair of functions is now in terms of .x and not y.

# `~.x` is evaluated as `~.x`, like I would want
tibble(y = 0L) %>%
  mutate(
    across(
      y,
      ~ list(list(
        rlang::as_function(~sum(.x)),
        rlang::as_function(~mean(.x))
      ))
    )
  ) %>%
  pull(y)
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]]
#> <lambda>
#> function (..., .x = ..1, .y = ..2, . = ..1) 
#> sum(.x)
#> <environment: 0x10b6a53e0>
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "rlang_lambda_function" "function"             
#> 
#> [[1]][[2]]
#> <lambda>
#> function (..., .x = ..1, .y = ..2, . = ..1) 
#> mean(.x)
#> <environment: 0x10b6a53e0>
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "rlang_lambda_function" "function"

I thought that quoting the formula might preserve the symbols, but quote(.x ~ .x) still ends up as y ~ y. I also tried using rlang::enexpr() and rlang::enquo() within formula_to_function_pair(), but had the same result.

# Both two sided formulas and quoted two sided formulas are `y ~ y`
tibble(y = 0L) %>%
  mutate(
    across(
      .cols = y,
      ~list(c(
        one_sided_quote = quote(~ .x),
        one_sided_formu = ~ .x,
        two_sided_quote = quote(.x ~ .x),
        two_sided_formu = .x ~ .x,
        another_random_quote = quote(z + 10)
      ))
    )
  ) %>%
  pull(y) %>%
  pluck(1)
#> $one_sided_quote
#> ~.x
#> 
#> $one_sided_formu
#> ~.x
#> <environment: 0x12c2e7958>
#> 
#> $two_sided_quote
#> y ~ y
#> 
#> $two_sided_formu
#> y ~ y
#> <environment: 0x12c2e7958>
#> 
#> $another_random_quote
#> z + 10

However, if in the ~ ... expression within across I also include the symbol .y (and seemingly only this symbol, maybe because of its use in rlang::as_function()?) then both the two-sided formula and two-sided quote are in terms of .x and not y.

# Adding `quote_dot_y = quote(.y + 10)` makes two-sided `.x ~ .x` work?
tibble(y = 0L) %>%
  mutate(
    across(
      .cols = y,
      ~list(c(
        one_sided_quote = quote(~ .x),
        one_sided_formu = ~ .x,
        two_sided_quote = quote(.x ~ .x),
        two_sided_formu = .x ~ .x,
        quote_dot_y = quote(.y + 10)
      ))
    )
  ) %>%
  pull(y) %>%
  pluck(1)
#> $one_sided_quote
#> ~.x
#> 
#> $one_sided_formu
#> ~.x
#> <environment: 0x103892900>
#> 
#> $two_sided_quote
#> .x ~ .x
#> 
#> $two_sided_formu
#> .x ~ .x
#> <environment: 0x103892900>
#> 
#> $quote_dot_y
#> .y + 10

This does, in a roundabout way, solve my problem - but isn't useable in practice.
tibble(y = 0L) %>%
  mutate(
    across(
      .cols = y,
      ~{
        quote(.y)
        list(formula_to_function_pair(sum(.x) ~ mean(.x)))
      }
    )
  ) %>%
  pull(y) %>%
  pluck(1)
#> $lhs_fun
#> function (.x) 
#> sum(.x)
#> <environment: 0x126bb86f8>
#> 
#> $rhs_fun
#> function (.x) 
#> mean(.x)
#> <environment: 0x126bb86f8>

Created on 2024-06-22 with reprex v2.0.2
So, two questions here:

Is there a nice way to get the behaviour I want (functions being in terms of .x and not y) by changing the definition of formula_to_function_pair()?
What is going on to make dplyr::across() interpret ~.x, .x ~ .x and {quote(.y); .x ~ .x} differently? This isn't as important - I'm just curious.


Edit: Taking a look at the code for dplyr::across() (thanks @moodymudskipper for pointing me in the right direction) I found the distinction between .x ~ .x and {quote(.y); .x ~ .x}.
quo_eval_fns(), used by across(), substitutes the symbols .x and . for the current column symbol (e.g. y) in .fns = ~ f(.x) if is_inlinable_formula(~ f(.x)) returns true.
The function is_inlinable_formula() checks for extra arguments in the formula expression via the pattern unsupported_arg_rx <- "\\.\\.[0-9]|\\.y", which includes .y, ..1, etc. If the formula expression contains any of these unsupported_arg_rx names, it is considered not inlinable.
So a formula .fns = ~ {quote(.y); list(.x ~ .x)} isn't inlined (does not have .x substituted for y), while .fns = ~ {list(.x ~ .x)} is inlined.

quoted from https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/6892 : "[across()] was designed to behave more like a macro than NSE". See this ticket to understand a bit better (it's not simple). It might help.

If you use mutate_at() it will work as you expect FWIW: mutate_at(., "y", ~ list(formula_to_function_pair(sum(.x) ~ mean(.x))))

or mutate(.,  across(y, function(x) list(formula_to_function_pair(sum(.x) ~ mean(.x)))), basically using a different argument name so the substitution is not triggered

That's helpful - thanks. I was hoping it would be possible to make it "just work" from a user perspective, but it looks like I might just have to caution against using a formula in across.
